# how to open a file from a GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback, load

How can I open a script in editor from a GUI push button callback?

I've tried:

```
function load_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

uiopen(myfile.m)
```

But it doesn't work!

Cheers,

Toby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open `file.m` in editor you need to use [`edit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/edit.html) command

```
edit file.m
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to use the function `open` Then you need to enquote the name of the file in the parameters like :

```
    open('myfile.m') %this will open the exact file 'myfile.m'
```

This will open the file in the editor.

You can use `uiopen` to let the user chose the file.

```
    uiopen() %this will prompt the user to choose file
```

I suggest you take a look here:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/open.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiopen.html